# Spaghetti JavaScript code to unwrap

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I wrote something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var a = new A();
    a.init();
};

A = function() {
    this.b = {};
};
A.prototype = {
    init : function() {
        document.writeln("init");
        this.b = new B();
        this.b.doCallback(this.init2);
    },

    init2 : function() {
        document.writeln("init2");
        this.b.say();
    }
};

B = function(){};
B.prototype = {
    doCallback: function(callback){
        callback();
    },

    say: function(){
        document.writeln("I'm B");
    }
};
```

For me output should look like this:

```
init
init2
I'm B
```

But insted, it looks like that:

```
init
init2
```

Chrome says that method 'say' is undefined. Could someone explain me why?

Comment: Change `this.b.doCallback(this.init2);` to `this.b.doCallback(this.init2.bind(this.b));`

Comment: Ah sorry prob. should be `this.init2.bind(this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because in your code `this` does not represent an instance of B.

> A function's this keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript
>   compared to other languages. It also has some differences between
>   strict mode and non-strict mode. In general, the object bound to this
>   in the current scope is determined by how the current function was
>   called, it can't be set by assignment during execution, and it can be
>   different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the bind
>   method to fix a function's this regardless of how it's called.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

So when you are calling `callback` which is `init2` , `this.b` is `null` and does not have any `say` method.

If you are using jQuery, you could use the method proxy http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

```
this.b.doCallback(jQuery.proxy(this.init2,this));
```

Comment: quirksmode is not the best reference regarding the `this` keyword, better link to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Thanks. I passed `this` to `doCallback` and then call `this.init2()`.  It's not so elegant, but it works.